# can respond.js process an internal stylesheet

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, modernizr, respond.js

I use modernizer.js & respond.js to implement media query on IE8.

I coded my page (HTML & Javascript) such as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Modernizr test page</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
        @media (max-width: 500px) {
            body {
            background-color: blue;
            }
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    Modernizr test page<br>

    <script src="modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    <script>
        Modernizr.load({
            test: Modernizr.mq('only all'),
            nope: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.js'
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It did not work.

---

I then changed my code to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Modernizr test page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="myStylesheet.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    Modernizr test page<br>

    <script src="modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    <script>
        Modernizr.load({
            test: Modernizr.mq('only all'),
            nope: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.js'
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And a separate CSS file "myStylesheet.css":

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
```

And it worked.

---

I had a quick look on [respond.js Github page](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) but could not find anything mentioned regarding internal stylesheet references not being supported.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Hi, good question. I'm getting the same behavior, and am interesting in it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems we have to connect respond.js after any styles internal or external. Then it should work!

Comment: If you look at my examples. `Respond.js` is added as the last thing in the code (just before the closing `</body>` tag)